# Serverless.yml AWS Lambda Embedding EJS Template into Handler.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to embed an EJS template named 'ui.ejs' into handler.js.
The aim is to capture URL query parameters, then pass them to a function name 'ui.js' to capture data, that data is then passed onto the EJS UI template called 'ui.ejs'.
But I keep getting this error:

```
Failure: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Studio\Work\YellowCard\dynamo_serverless_rest\.webpack\service/views/ui.ejs'
```

Seems webpack is interfering with my directory paths.
The directory is under '/views/ui.ejs' NOT '.webpack\service/views/ui.ejs' like the error claims.
How do I fix it?
Thanks in advance..!

Here's the handler.js code:

```
// Import modules and dependencies
import {ui} from './index.js';
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');

// Implementing the UI
export async function UserInterface(event, context, callback) {

    // Capture data event parameters
    const e = event.queryStringParameters;

    // Get UI parameters
    let params = await ui(e);

    var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/' + 'ui.ejs', 'utf8');

    var template = ejs.compile(htmlContent);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/html' },
      body: JSON.stringify(template(params)),
      };

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy the views folder to the destination directory.

In your webpack configuration file (`webpack.config.js`)

```
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
// ...

  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "views", to: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack', 'service', 'views') },
      ],
    }),
  ],
```

And also update serverless.yml file to include views directory to your lambda function

```
package:
  include:
    - views/**
```

Answer (score 0):

The Fix:
I found a quick solution using the 'path' module.

```js
import {ui} from './index.js';
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Implementing the UI
export async function UserInterface(event, context, callback) {

    // Capture data event
    const e = event.queryStringParameters;

    // Get UI parameters
    let params = await ui(e);

    var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(process.cwd(), './views/' + 'ui.ejs'), 'utf8');

    var template = ejs.compile(htmlContent);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/html' },
      body: JSON.stringify(template(params)),
      };

};
```